# Share cookies just with one subdomain

Tags: symfony, cookies

I have an inherited project.

I got two environments, one for beta and one in production.

Production enviroment got a subdomain, the cookie of domain must be shared whit this subdomain, but not with the beta enviroment subdomain.

Example:

- **Prod env**: mydomain.com
- **Prod env**: live.mydomain.com *(Cookie shared with mydomain.com)*
- **Beta env**: beta.mydomain.com *(Cookies shouldn't shared)*

Someone knows a way to do this? :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this can be done, but (UNTESTED) you could try to use [cookie_domain](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#cookie-domain) key into configuration of your app along with Regex

Something like

```
#config.yml
framework:
    session:
        cookie_domain: ^(?!beta).*\.my-domain\.com$
```

Not sure if `cookie_domain` accepts Regex but you can give it a try and let us know if this works.